# Unable to inspect GML file

Tags: fme-form, xml, gml

I use FME to make GML file based on SQLServer data. When I create GML, I cann't see anything in FME Data Inspector or Universal Viewer. Like something is missing in file.
I have schema, and XMLValidator validates file against schema, but I still cann't see graphical data.

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8kUf-xMW81XY09lV2prQ3VUVlE/edit?usp=sharing) to Result.gml

[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8kUf-xMW81XNlJ4dFVLS1cyTVE/edit?usp=sharing) to schema.

Does anyone knows what is the problem and what is missing in schema?

**EDIT:**

As requested! [image: FME workspace]

This is just a part, but main part. All features come into XMLTemplater, like on the picture. Some of them (with non-point geometry) goes first in GeometryExtractor and then into XMLTemplater. These StringReplacers works fine. XMLValidator validates document successfully.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your FME Workbench?

Comment: @Fezter Uploaded and explained.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious issue is that the GML file doesn't have a reference to the xsd schema document. Without that FME has no information on how the dataset is structured. Whatever template you are using in the XMLTemplater, you need to include that reference. Then FME will be able to view the data correctly.

Comment: I use text file as writer, so I don't know where to define schemaLocation in FME. Text file is used because I couldn't manage GML as I wanted.

Comment: Where is the template coming from in the XMLTemplater? That's where the schema definition should be included.